# PC System keeps crashing due to overheating

Tags: cpu, power-supply, crash, temperature, overheating

In October I had the problem the first time. My desktop PC crashed as if the power would just be gone. But it only occured when I had my case closed, so I opened it and everything was fine. But yesterday it started crashing again.

I assume a component is overheating but I'm not sure which one it is. The possibilities are (I think):

- Power supply
- Processor
- Mainboard chipset

According to Open Hardware Monitor the temperatures of my processor (AMD FX-6100) is 45 °C writing this post, 60-70 °C watching a video and 70-80 °C in a video game.
The chipset (ITE IT8720F) has 3 temperatures that go from 40/60/60 °C (browser) over 45/80/85 °C (video) to 50/90/95 °C.

GPU is always under 45 °C

The only other additional information I can give is that the shutdown makes exactly the sound as if you would just pull the plug.

How can I determine which component is actually problematic?

Comment: You've probably already checked this, but just in case you haven't, open the case and use an air duster to clean out all the dust and dust bunnies.  You might need to remove the fan from the heat sink to get all the dust/lint from between the heat sink blades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing every bit of dust I could access (especially under the CPU fan) my computer runs crash free even with close cased. Additionally I added a bit of WD-40 on the fan.

The only problem is, that the displayed CPU temperature might bi not so accurate, because I doubt it can be 12 °C while the room has 20 °C. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your processor and chipset temperatures under load seem pretty high. What type of CPU fan are you using? What are your ambient (room) temperatures?

Here are a few things to check:

- Is your CPU fan running?
- Chipset idle temperature in the BIOS (this way you know which number is accurate in your harware monitor).

You might consider getting an aftermarket CPU cooler if the fan is working properly, though AMD stock coolers are usually pretty good. Re-applying thermal paste could also help.

Comment: After a fresh start and 5 mins in BIOS my CPU has 60 °C. A bit too much I guess in idle

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely too high. You can get a nice aftermarket cooler for less than $30, but first I'd check to make sure the CPU fan is running.

Comment: Its running with 3500 rpm, guess that should be enough normally.

Comment: Yeah that is normal, is it pretty hot in the room you're in?

Comment: around 20 normally